# Getting an image from UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Any ideas on how to get an Image from UITextView?

```
NSString *string=@"";
self.textview.text=string;
UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
image.image=_textview.textContainer;
```

I was thinking something like that but its not right

Comment: What is textContainer here ?

Comment: What you actually want, did you want to draw textField with it's text as an image or something else.

Comment: basically use an (UITextview) + a (save Button) when its tapped it will display an Image @AnandK

Comment: [Swift answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37054129/3681880)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *string=@"write your text";
self.textview.text=string;
UIImage *image = [self makeImageWithRect:self.textview.frame];// get image from rectangle for textview 
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
imageView.image=image;


-(UIImage*)makeImageWithRect:(CGRect)rect {

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return viewImage;
}
```

/*code for saving image to photo album*/

```
/* Save to the photo album */
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave ,
                               self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
                               @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
                               NULL); // you generally won't need a contextInfo here);

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Name" message:@"Image saved to photo album" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];

- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
if (error) {
    // Do anything needed to handle the error or display it to the user
} else {
    // .... do anything you want here to handle
    // .... when the image has been saved in the photo album
}
}
```

**here is the code which i  use for saving a snapshot of whole screen**

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender {

UIView* captureView = self.ContainerView;

/* Capture the screen shoot at native resolution */
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureView.bounds.size, captureView.opaque, 0.0);
[captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

/* Render the screen shot at custom resolution */
CGRect cropRect = self.view.frame;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, captureView.opaque, 1.0f);
[screenshot drawInRect:cropRect];
UIImage * customScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImage *imageToSave =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[customScreenShot CGImage]
                    scale:1.0
              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];

/* Save to the photo album */
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave ,
                               self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
                               @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
                               NULL); // you generally won't need a contextInfo here);

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Name" message:@"Image saved to photo album" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
}

- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
if (error) {
    // Do anything needed to handle the error or display it to the user
} else {
    // .... do anything you want here to handle
    // .... when the image has been saved in the photo album
}
}
```

Comment: can i put the method inside of a UIBUTTON when the user clicked it ,it will return the Image that they could save in the camera  roll @pawan

Comment: @yes , after getting image you need to write save image code

Comment: sorry to ask again so i put the last method in the my button right

Comment: yes , imageToSave is the image which you need to save in photo album.