# How to convert text to UIImage (use GPU)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, cpu

I know have many questions like this on `stackoverflow`and also have the answer for it like on this link: [How to convert text to Image on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556269/how-to-convert-text-to-image). But with me, I need to draw many (more than 800 image) UIImages. So that, if I do my job as follow:

```
func createImage(text: String, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {

    let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let drawText = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 15)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
        ]

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    drawText?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

My **app will run so very slowly** ~  ***app get jerky***. I hear about the `GPU acceleration` but don't have any experience on `GPU`. How to draw image (as my function) but use the `GPU` to do this?

Answer (score 0):

UIKit is already using graphics acceleration. Your problem probably is running this method on the main thread.

I dont't know what your app should do without any other context, but you should move the execution of this method to a background thread.

If you need to process a big number of images this way, think about using NSOperationQueue.
Have a look there: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue

Comment: Any comment on why it got downvoted? I don't see any reason, it is legitimate advice.

Comment: You answer does not answer the question. The question is about sending the work to the GPU.